# How to show a global loader when pages are loading in .NET Blazor Server app?

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

In .NET Blazor WebAssembly app I can add the loader in index.html like this:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!--Overlay Loader-->
    <div id="PageOverlay">
        <div class="loader">
            <div id="PageOverlaySvgBox" class="hat-logo"></div>
            <h1 data-bind="text:label" class="text-primary">جاري تحميل الصفحة...</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
```

But in Blazor Server app there is no index.html, what I found is _Host.cshtml.

```
<body>
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </environment>
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

But where should I add my loader?

Or, where or how to show a loader on loading any page?

Comment: You should have an `App.razor` file that you could use, or integrate your loader in a Layout. Your Loader can also be integrated wherever you want if you make it as a Blazor component.

Comment: Is there a way to show a component on page load and then hide it when finish loading, without using javascript.

Comment: Yes, this is kind of the purpose of Blazor to manage rendering.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74073551/blazor-server-app-how-is-this-loading-progress-working-is-it-in-a-loop) for a specific page and situation, fully explained, since i don't know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This example is for one page. What I want is to show a loader when the application first load or when refreshing any page.